# Display image backgound in its original size on top of another background

Tags: html, css

image2 is a wallpaper size jpg and image1 is a small image.

Why did image1 scale larger and how do I display it in its original size on top of image2?

```
html {
      background: url("image1.jpg") no-repeat, url("image2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle or a snippet to reproduce the problem ? i cannot reproduce it

Comment: image1 is stretching with the size of the screen, question is how to display image1 in original size in html css selector.

Comment: well in your question you say something about image2 stretching, now you are saying about image1 :) . please be more clear and give all the necessary information ( preferably a working example )

Comment: sorry, I corrected my question.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gwomzo?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear but I will do my best to help.

First I would check out this article about background image stacking it will help you in terms of the order:

https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

I would suggest you need to do the following:

```
html {
  background: 
    url("image2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed,
    url("image1.jpg") no-repeat; 
}
```

You may also need a fallback depending on browser support.

If you can provide a codepen it would help

Answer (score -1):

try something like

```
html {
  background: 
    url("image1.jpg") 
    no-repeat; 
}
.image2 {
    url("image2.jpg") 
    no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

---

```
    <html>
     <div class="image2"></div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is html tag background image will always stretch no way around it.